# Show an image based on date

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to show a check mark image based on date, the date format is **March 28, 2021** for an event list

For example:

if the event date is on **March 29, 2021**
then it will show the following image (green checkbox)

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/iw9fm7A.jpg">
```

but if today date was March 28, 2021, and the event has not happened yet
then it will not show any images, just blank.

Code:

```
<table width="80%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Event Name</td>
    <td>Event Date</td>
    <td>Completed? </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-Bike meet up at <strong>Los Angeles, Griffith Park</strong></td>
    <td>March 29, 2021</td>
    <td>Show Checkbox Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-Bike meet up at <strong>Los Angeles, State Historic Park</strong></td>
    <td>April 5, 2021</td>
    <td>Leave empty</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no code in your question. Please read [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm not seeing any attempts on your part here. How would you know to use what image? Perhaps you want to use two Arrays along with the `Date` constructor?

Comment: Please see my my edits, its just a table table, we use for events but would like to to make the check box appear automatically based on today's date  and the event date

Answer (score 1):

The short script below will loop through the table cells having the `date` class that I added to your HTML.

It will parse it as a number representing the amount of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. Then it will compare that number with today's amount of milliseconds. If the parsed date from the table is past, it will add the image's HTML to the next sibling cell or make it empty.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".date").forEach(d=>{
  d.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = (Date.parse(d.innerText)<Date.now()) ? '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/iw9fm7A.jpg">' : ''
})
```

```html
<table width="80%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Event Name</td>
    <td>Event Date</td>
    <td>Completed? </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-Bike meet up at <strong>Los Angeles, Griffith Park</strong></td>
    <td class="date">March 29, 2021</td>
    <td>Show Checkbox Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-Bike meet up at <strong>Los Angeles, State Historic Park</strong></td>
    <td class="date">April 5, 2021</td>
    <td>Leave empty</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Some documentation to look at if your are curious about how it works:

- [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)
- [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting an error on line  document.querySelectorAll

Comment: Make sure you add `class="date"` in the HTML.